# Internet Explorer making up CSS for BODY

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background-color

Here is Internet Explorer showing me my CSS:
[image: My CSS]

See that line I've selected yeah that's not there in the CSS. Infact it's specifically something else:

```
/*
Copyright (c) 2003-2013, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
For licensing, see LICENSE.html or http://ckeditor.com/license
*/

body
{
/* Font */
font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, "Trebuchet MS";
font-size: 12px;

/* Text color */
color: #333;

/* Remove the background color to make it transparent */
background-color: transparent !important;

margin: 20px;
}
```

You'll notice that I'm trying to make the background to a CKEditor 10 transparent. You'll also notice that IE seems to be making $h1t up.

Any ideas how I can tell IE to stop doing this and make the background transparent?

I have also tried to remove the background style, it ignores that. I've also cleared the cache and still no joy. As you can probably guess Chrome and other good browsers work fine.

Comment: Try `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) !important;`

Comment: I'll assume you're dealing with an iframe, since a transparent main document body won't do anything. If the rgba solution doesn't work, try setting `allowtransparency="true"` on your iframe

Comment: The rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) makes no difference.

Comment: The allowtransparency option is unavailable it's generated by CKEditor, however the IFrame is transparent it's the body that isn't. If I untick the option highlighted above it's transparent.

Comment: Here's a kicker, it IS transparent on my localhost.
I am using <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

Comment: Forget it, I've solved the problem by clearing my Temporary internet files. The CSS files was being cached even beyond clearing the cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS reset to override browser's default CSS
http://www.cssreset.com/